# Duplicating and De-duplicating strings in R

Tags: r, string, duplicates

I have the following strings (actually hundreds more)

```
101100    (Unique String 1)
101100
101100
101100
101100
111010    (Unique string 2)
101010    (Unique string 3)
```

The first 5 strings are identical, whereas the last 2 are distinct.

In a table, this would look like

```
Unique String 1   Unique String 2   Unique String 3
      5                 1                 1
```

**My question is**: In R, Is there a way to de-duplicate the most frequent string (101100) and duplicate the other strings randomly, such that the number of total strings is conserved? By randomly, I mean without specifying an 'each = ' argument, say?

The new table might look like

```
Unique String 1   Unique String 2   Unique String 3
      3                 2                 2
```

corresponding to the strings

```
101100    (Unique String 1)
101100
101100
111010    (Unique string 2)
111010
101010    (Unique string 3)
101010
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need `rep`:

```
v <- c(rep("101100", 5), "111010", "101010")

v_unique <- unique(v)

t1 <- table(v)
# reproduce original
rep(v_unique, t1)

# other frequencies
t2 <- c(3, 2, 2)
rep(v_unique, t2)
# "101100" "101100" "101100" "111010" "111010" "101010" "101010"
```

Comment: Thanks. My data is of type 'raw', so I get an error when I try do                           res <- res[rep(nrow(res), t2), ]. If I specify each = t2 in rep(), only the first element is used. Any ideas?

Comment: Nrow give a result of length 1. In this case rep only produces t2 cases of nrow  (if anything). I don't get the purpose of the slicing. There seems to be something missing in the question.